# Second monitor not rendering correctly with NVidia drivers

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and NVidia Drivers 346. I have a Samsung monitor and it works nice except because it does not appear to render correctly.

For example, when I scroll a page or something, it does not render. When I move my mouse, the screen renders the content "in the back", but only where I moved my mouse. Like if the old content stay above the new content. It's hard to explain.

It appears that the second display has a delay rendering. It only renders the full content when something force it. I cannot give a screen shot because the printscreen is included in this "force rendering" list. So, when I try to do it, the screen renders and nothing appears to be wrong.

**EDIT**:
I can notice that right in the middle of the screen, in diagonal, it makes a division when this problem occurs. Like the monitor were divided in to sides in the diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking on bugs.launchpad.net i see that your card is afflicted by a bug 
since driver version 331

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1408567

take a look to the thread , is very similar to your situation

Comment: sorry dude looks like you have to wait a little bit, this why before buy a video card for your linux system is a good precaution to analyze a lot of forum watching at users feedbacks ....u never know ;)

Comment: Yeah, sure. It's a laptop. Next time I'll be more cautious.

Answer (score 0):

mmm......maybe i'm missleaded ...but consider 2 things

1) does it happen with open drivers too?( this checks if is a monitor related issue or a software one)
2)disable compositing and try again....

if the problem stay still , maybe is a monitor issue

cause dude , i got 2 PCs with two nvidia card one with nvs5200 aboard the other one with a GTX660ti both with two monitors connected and nor one gave problems ever.
 and of course i use 346 drivers too

Comment: 1) No. With nouveau, the screen renders pretty nice;
2) Disabled. And the problem persists.
These two video cards you have are running with NVidia drivers?

Comment: yes they're both running on nvidia proprietary drivers...what's your nvidia card name ?? ( run *lspci* and paste the output )

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09);

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)